# Javascript - populate a div with content from a hidden div using click buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click, display

I need some help. As you will see in my fiddle, I am attempting to use buttons to populate a single container div with content from multiple hidden divs, depending on which button is clicked. The problem I am having is, I don't know how to access the actual content in the hidden divs to populate the container div. As of now, I am using the id attributes for the hidden divs to demonstrate which div content I would like to display in the container.

I've seen a few other posts with link `<a>` attributes referencing hidden content, but none so far using a button element with click functionality to change div content.

```js
    jQuery(function ($) {
      $('#button1').click(function () {
        $('#info').empty();
        $('#info').prepend('#option1');
      });

      $('#button2').click(function () {
        $('#info').empty();
        $('#info').prepend('#option2');
      });
      
      $('#button3').click(function () {
        $('#info').empty();
        $('#info').prepend('#option3');
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-panel">
  <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
   <li class="buttons"><button id="button1">Button 1</button></li>
   <li class="buttons"><button id="button2">Button 2</button></li>
   <li class="buttons"><button id="button3">Button 3</button></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="info-div">
  <div id="info"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="hiddenDivs" style="display:none;">
  <div class="info" id="option1">Box</div>
  <div class="info" id="option2">Google Drive</div>
  <div class="info" id="option3">Box</div>
 </div>
```

Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lcunning/yvsu6qfw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version that uses jquery data attributes. It reduces the redundancy and complexity and can be configured easily.

```
<body>
        <div class="button-panel">
            <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button1" data-link="option1">Button 1</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button2" data-link="option2">Button 2</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button3" data-link="option3">Button 3</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="info-div">
            <div id="info">

            </div>
        </div>
<div id="hiddenDivs" style="display:none;">
    <div class="info" id="option1">Box</div>
    <div class="info" id="option2">Google Drive</div>
    <div class="info" id="option3">Box</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
   $('.buttons button').click(function (){
        $('#info').empty();
        $('#info').html($("#" + $(this).data('link')).html());
    });   
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/yvsu6qfw/3/

Comment: Thank you SO much! This works exactly the way I need it to. You rock!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Dino, can you please help me understand the use of ("#" + $(this).data('link') ?

Comment: @icunning,  $(this).data('link') extracts the data-attr 'link' of button element, which gives you either option1, option2, option3 etc. '#' is used as an id identifier, so after the whole expression, you get ('#option1")

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, and your answer! Helped me get a prototype finished. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe you were looking for using the button itself to populate data built into the button with a data attribute or something? If so you can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-panel">
    <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="buttons"><button data-info="Box">Button 1</button></li>
        <li class="buttons"><button data-info="Google Drive">Button 2</button></li>
        <li class="buttons"><button data-info="Box">Button 3</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="info-div">
    <div id="info"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#button-column button').click(function (){
        $('#info').html($(this).attr('data-info'));
    });
 });
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I've chosen another that suits my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first button to load the content from the first hidden div etc. without relying upon using the id attributes, you can use the [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method. When you pass `this` as an argument it will return the index value of the click event target in the collection `$("#button-column .buttons :button")`. Afterwards you can pass the index value to the [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get1) method to retrieve the corresponding element from the collection of hidden divs `$("#hiddenDivs .info")`.

```
$().ready(function(){
  $("#button-column .buttons :button").on("click", function(){
    $('#info').empty();
    var clickedIndex = $("#button-column .buttons :button").index(this);
    var hiddenInfo = $("#hiddenDivs .info").get(clickedIndex);
    $('#info').prepend( $(hiddenInfo).text() );
  });
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I've chosen another that suits my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html function, without parameter gets the content of the element
with parameter replaces the content with the string parameter

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#button1').click(function (){
        $('#info').html( $('#option1').html()  );
    });
    $('#button2').click(function (){
                $('#info').html( $('#option2').html()  );
    });
    $('#button3').click(function (){
            $('#info').html( $('#option3').html() );
    });
 });
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I've chosen another that suits my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, you do for example:

```
$('#info').prepend('#option1');
```

What you instruct to do here, is adding a text string '#option1' to an element with ID info.

What you intend to do is prepending the content of ID option1 to the element with ID info. You could do something like this instead:

```
$('#info').prepend($('#option1').html());
```

Another approach could be (but I don't know if that's relevant for you) to not clone content (since it costs you repaints) but toggle the specific elements instead. For example:

```
$('#option1,#option2').hide();
$('#option3').hide();
```

And yet another one: use data-attributes on your buttons:

```
<a href="#" data-text="Box" class="button">Button 1</a>
<a href="#" data-text="Another text" class="button">Button 2</a>
<div id="info">

</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#info').html($(event.currentTarget).attr('data-text'));
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I've chosen another that suits my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat yourself! To get the number out of an ID replace with `""` all that is not a number using RegExp `\D`.

#### Using number from ID

Than, to get the actual content you can use `$("#option"+ num).html()` or `$("#option"+ num).text()` methods:

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yvsu6qfw/2/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  $('.buttons button').click(function () {
      var num = this.id.replace(/\D/g,"");
      $("#info").html( $("#option"+ num).html() );
  });

});
```

#### Target element using `data-*` attribute

Alternatively you can store inside a `data-*` attribute the desired target selector ID:

```
<button data-content="#option1" id="button1">Button 1</button>
```

and than simply:

[jsFiddle  demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yvsu6qfw/5/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  $("[data-content]").click(function () {
      $("#info").html( $(this.dataset.content).html() );
  });

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/
http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I've chosen another that suits my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If the expectation is to get same indexed hidden div content, Then the below code should work.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $('.buttons button').click(function (){
            $('#info').empty();

            var index = $('.buttons button').index($(this));
            $('#info').html($('.info:eq('+index+')').html());
        });
    });
```